# How to show errors for the particular field , that is generated via aura iterations

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am creating a multiple rows with textbox via aura iteration and on click of the button i want to show error to the row which having errors such as blank textbox or invalid number.
I can iterate and found the error but dont know to how to show the error like V.Error, "Invalid Input" to that particular row.
Currently showing with message box.

Please help 
Thanks
Pandi

Answer (score 3):

So this you can achieve with the help of `lightning:input` component just by adjusting some attributes value of this component as `required`, `maxlength` etc.

**Component part**

```
<aura:component>
  <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="First name" name="firstname" placeholder="First name" required="true" />
  <lightning:input aura:id="field" label="Last name" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" required="true" />
  <lightning:select aura:id="field" label="Select the best ice cream flavor" name="flavor" required="true">
    <option value="">Choose a flavor...</option>
    <option value="vanilla">Vanilla</option>
    <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
    <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
  </lightning:select>
  <lightning:textarea aura:id="field" label="Why did you choose this flavor?" name="reason" placeholder="I chose this ice cream flavor because..." />
  <lightning:button aura:id="submit" type="submit" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.onClick }" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller part**

```
({
  onClick: function (cmp, evt, helper) {
    var allValid = cmp.find('field').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
        inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
        return validSoFar && inputCmp.get('v.validity').valid;
    }, true);


    if (!allValid) {
      return; //something is invalid so user will see the meaningful error message on the respected field.
    }
    //@todo call server action to save data.
  }
})
```

**NOTE:** *All the fields must have the same aura:id value.* In this example, the `aura:id` value is `field`.

More you can read on [lightning:input in Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/example#lightningComponentDemo:exampleInputValidation).

PS: You can also bookmark the component library for future references.

Comment: HI.Thanks for the reply, I am trying with <UI:Input> And i am creating the elements in <Aura:Iterations> so if any error comes my requirement is to show the error in the row of error. Can be achieve?

Comment: So this validation only works with the `lightning:input` component, If you want to use the `ui:inputText` then you can do that as well but for the you need to set the `v.errors` attribute of the element which contains errors and the v.errors is an array of Map and the message key is required. Hope this helps you.

Comment: HI,I created as below <aura:iteration var="opp" items="{!v.parti}">                   
                    <tr><td><ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="partId" text="{!opp.Code__c}"  name="" label="" change="{!c.getSelectedParty}"/></td><td>{!opp.Name}</td><td> <ui:inputText value="" maxlength="5" aura:id="goalVal"   /> </td> </tr></aura:iteration> And on click of the button i am looping it and able to find it  which is missing but how to set the specific row is empty? can you please help on this. Thanks

Comment: Sure, will look into this, a small request to you please post the updated code in the question or better to ask a new question with the UI:... items as this all discussion is about lightning:... elements.

Comment: And post new question link here in the comments.